# Mongodb C# how do I set newCollectionsUsePowerOf2Sizes=false;

Tags: mongodb

I am creating a large number of documents and collections and would like to set newCollectionsUsePowerOf2Sizes=false

What is the C# code to set this property.

thanks

Comment: [`newCollectionsUsePowerOf2Size`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/parameters/#param.newCollectionsUsePowerOf2Sizes) is a MongoDB 2.6 server-level parameter. Are you looking to change the default for the entire server, or just for the new collections you are creating?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried this with C# but in mongoshell we can do this:-

```
db.runCommand( {collMod: "products", usePowerOf2Sizes : true })
```

This same command can be send using java driver using this function in DB api ([link](http://api.mongodb.org/java/current/com/mongodb/DB.html#command(com.mongodb.DBObject))):-

```
public CommandResult command(DBObject cmd)
```

You can find a C# equivalent of this. Hope this helps.